# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null after status 200 OK?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeoutexception

I am presently developing a Java 11 Spring boot application.
Within a CompletableFuture I am firing a load of REST requests to a webservice. Only one of them (randomly it seems) results in a TimeoutException though it is followed by a successful status 200 OK received response in the logging. Following the (anonymized) log entries:

```
[Thread-6] INFO  n.d.b.a.b.i.RESTInterceptor - Request              : <url value>?code=abcd&begindatum=2018-10-01&einddatum=2018-10-02
[http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/xxx] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException] with root cause
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Timeout.run(CompletableFuture.java:2792)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[Thread-6] DEBUG n.d.b.a.b.i.RESTInterceptor - Response statuscode  : 200 OK
[Thread-6] DEBUG n.d.b.a.b.i.RESTInterceptor - Response headers     : [X-Application-Context:"yyyy", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", Server:"CD", X-Powered-By:"Unknown", Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Date:"Tue, 06 Apr 2021 15:23:16 GMT", Connection:"close", X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN", X-XSS-Protection:"1;mode=block", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff"]
[Thread-6] INFO  n.d.b.a.b.i.RESTInterceptor - Response             : [{"begindatum":"1993-01-01","id":"aaaaa","vanInstellingserkenningId":"bbbbb","naarInstellingserkenningId":"ccccc","soort":"HIERARCHISCH","naarInstellingserkenning":{"id":"ddddd","type":"ERKENDE_ONDERWIJSINSTELLING","code":"abcd"},"vanInstellingserkenning":{"id":"kkkk","type":"BEVOEGD_GEZAG","code":"12345"}}]
```

Is there someone having the same experience? I cannot see any difference in the successfully completed requests and the 'failing' one.

Comment: Well, without any code it's hard to help. My guess would be that you're catching the exception (or the system is), log it and still return a 200.

Answer (score 1):

After deeper analysis of the problem I finally found out that the TimeoutException is thrown from another Future's handling, elsewhere in the application. The confusion I had that the handling of futures (asynchronous tasks, each in their own Thread) is not what it looks like in a log-file. The shown TimeoutException in the log-snippet is not thrown in the request-response interaction that is shown.
Sorry for the confusion, but maybe others may be helped by this answer.